# Sometimes imagebutton click event not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that add's an onclick event too an imagebutton.
But sometimes you have to press the button multiple times before the "pop-up" window opens.
Any idea why this happens?

this is my code were I add the event to my imagebutton:

```
private void AddProjectDetails()
    {
        ImageButton imgBtn;
        HiddenField hfld;
        String ProjectNumber;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridViewProperties.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            hfld = GridViewProperties.Rows[i].FindControl("HiddenProjId") as HiddenField;
            imgBtn = GridViewProperties.Rows[i].FindControl("ibtnShowExtra") as ImageButton;
            ProjectNumber = hfld.Value;
            imgBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjectNumber=" + Server.UrlEncode(ProjectNumber) + "','Graph','height=590,width=600,left=50,top=50,scrollbars=yes'); return true;");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning false from the javascript. This will prevent postback. Some times the postback can be faster then the windows.open, and in this case I don't think you want it.

Another solution is using an `<a href='...' >image</a>` instead of the imagebutton

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `return true` inside you java-script function.

Do you need postback on your page.
If not use `return false`.

I will also suggest you to write a javascript function and call it as follows

```
function OpenPopUp(projectNumber) 
{
      window.open("ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjectNumber="+ projectNumber 
                      ,'Graph','height=590,width=600,left=50,top=50,scrollbars=yes'); 
      return false;
};
```

and call it inside your c# code

```
imgBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return OpenPopUp('"+Server.UrlEncode(ProjectNumber)+"');");
```

Comment: What'S the advantage of doing it in a seperate function?

Answer (score 0):

Like Stefano and Shekhar said, you must not use return true for LinkButtons, Imagebuttons, unless you want the page post back.

You can also use this way:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonOpenProject" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/OpenProject.png"  OnClientClick="return OpenProject('"<%# ProjectNumber %>"');" />
```

And in your JavaScript script you do something like this:

```
function OpenProject(ProjectNumber){
    window.open('ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjectNumber=' + ProjectNumber + ','Graph','height=590,width=600,left=50,top=50,scrollbars=yes');
    return false;
}
```

Hope this help.